# How to disable battery charging?

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, battery, charging

From the `pmset` man page:

> POWER SOURCE ARGUMENTS
>
> `-g` with a 'batt' or 'ps' argument will show the state of all attached power sources.
>
> […] Certain Apple battery calibration tools may temporarily disable
>   battery charging, even though your Apple portable is plugged into AC
>   power.
>
> Such tools will never surprise you with this behavior; you will know
>   it's happening. This state will be reflected in an additional line of
>   output to 'batt' or 'ps' readings, including the `pid` of the app
>   inducing this behavior.
>
> ```
>      'ChargeInhibit':    1432
> ```

So, does any piece of publicly available software exist to force the battery not to charge?

Comment: I am a little bit curious here, why would someone want to do something like that? Batteries are meant to be charged and dis-charged to keep them healthy. Also, once the battery is fully charged will stop of course.

Comment: The SMC already prevents charging if starting with a 93% or higher battery level, but a Li-Ion battery is ideally stored at about 40%. I am one of those who hardly ever move their computer from the desk.

Comment: Okay, now I understand the point. However, you will be fine by just having the battery fully charged and discharge it to 20 % at least once per month. The benefit of storage at 40% is more important if you are planning to store your battery for a year or so without using it.

Comment: And that damn SMC design always cause me to worry about the healthiness of my battery. LOL!

Comment: Hi, I tried to find this out some years ago... but I was not able to find anything. My idea was to control the charging of my macs with the power generation of my windmill :-)

Comment: I need this because my solar panels can't both charge AND run my computer at the some time (either is fine)

Comment: It is so unfortunate that we don't have an answer to this in software. It would really be helpful to extend battery life. I'm also surprised Apple does not provide this out of the box.

Comment: You might want to look into tools like [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente) (comes with a GUI), or [bclm](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm) (CLI).

Those are softwares that write to the BCLM (battery charge level max) of SMC, so you can set a upper limit to which your Mac will charge its battery.

Answer (score 46):

If you use a small piece of tape to block the middle (signal) pin on your MagSafe charger, your Mac will not charge because it can't identify the charger.

[image]

Comment: If you remove the charger it also won't change.

Comment: Of course, but OP wanted to know how to disable charging "even though your Apple portable is plugged into AC power."

Comment: I confirm, this works. I am able to stay at 40% charge forever while using AC power, which is exactly what OP wanted, albeit the solution is not software but hardware :) I have Magsafe 2

Comment: As the days go by, I can see the percentage slowly drop due to self-discharge. This is awesome solution for MacBooks used as servers, or MacBooks used as desktops. This answer deserves more upvotes!

Comment: Yep! On laptops whose CPUs have higher TDPs, you might notice that the battery level also drops when you make the computer work hard and the charger can't provide all the power needed.

Comment: I used this to make my MacBook work with an underpowered car inverter so it would draw less power and it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: So it does not charge the battery, but it does use the power for normal consumption. Nice solution!

Comment: This is gold. I wish I knew this right after I started using my laptop. Many thanks for the tip!

Comment: Careful with this.  Worked for months, then it smoked a charged almost damaged my mac and started a fire. Charger tip melted and burnt the charging port where the MagSafe connects. I used transparent tape like the photo. Maybe I should have used electrical tape. But, I think a timer like yurkennis suggest is safer.

Comment: can anyone test this with the new magsafe 3?

Answer (score 1):

Not an Apple-approved answer, but to solve your root cause (to train battery regularly when your MBP is always at your desk), consider surge protectors with scheduled on/off ([example](http://www.inter-step.com/catalog/InterStep-techno/setevie-filtri.18/setevoy-filtr-SP-206T.259.html), about $40 in Russia). You can program it to turn off in the beginning of night, and to turn on about 4am so that battery is charged back by the time you show up at your desk. To save charge cycles, I believe it should be performed not daily--but maybe once or twice a week.

Comment: how many rubles is that :) great and effective answer +10

Comment: A simple timer ($5,-) would do the same, right?

Comment: @cousincocaine Much more manual work, isn't it?

Comment: No, is digital, not much work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to disable charging while plugged in (if you have a non-removable battery, as recent models do).

Apple used to make an [Airline MagSafe Adapter](http://pangea.stanford.edu/~schmitt/magsafe/#airline) (which didn't charge computers, so as to avoid tripping the airplane outlet's circuit breaker (or whatever the cause) that resulted in no power being provided at all), but it was discontinued years ago.

Your computer will automatically stop charging once it reaches a high enough charge. You can't "disable charging" except by already having a charged battery.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to discontinue charging while it is plugged in. This is a default function that enables as soon as you plug your portable charger in power source, and if any software does that, then it is surely going to harm you device as well as battery even more. So it is better to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

My Magsafe currently has one of the outer pins stuck in, I cant seem to get it to come out, Ive ordered a new chord, but the interesting thing is that its not charging the battery. It is powering the Macbook pro, but my battery percentage is not going up. maybe try sticking some PVC tape over one of the outer contacts if you don't want the battery to charge?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is basically repeating [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132332/121968), though that speaks of the middle contact instead of the outer ones.

Answer (score -2):

When I opened the cord (between the transformer and the magsafe connector) for the charger on my macbook pro, there were only 2 wires.
 Therefore its seems likely that the tiny middle pin on the magsafe connector does not do anything electrical !