# How to charge the MacBook Pro from 12 Volts?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, charging

Aim: I would like to charge my MacBook Pro (MBP) form a 12V lead-acid battery. However there are no official chargers from Apple for that purpose. There exist quite some alternative products on the internet. For example [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00823OLUM) simply comes with a MagSafe adapter and lets you choose 18V. However I am afraid that such a solution might hurt my battery.

Does anybody know how exactly the MBP battery is charged? Does it require a particular charge line? Is it OK to simply connect 18 Volts and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect 18 V to the power/ground pins, your Mac will be powered off the 12 V battery, but it won't charge: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132332/26231

To charge, the laptop needs to identify the charger by communicating over the signal pin in the middle. http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html

Solution: Sacrifice an apple charger by cutting the cable and connecting the correct pins to your DC/DC converter. I recommend using the 45 W ones so your DC power supply doesn't have to be very big.

Comment: Thanks! Will the MacBook limit power consumption to 45W in your example or draw whatever it can?

Comment: Yeah, if you cut the cable from a 45 W charger, the Mac will read the chip in the connector and identify the charger

Comment: ok. finally did it. got an efficient dc/dc converter and a new magsafe cable from ebay. works.

Comment: Hey @n1000 thanks for the great question and comment. Please may I have suggestions on which DC/DC converter to buy?

Comment: @nslntmnx Mine is similar to [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Geeetech-Converter-10-32V-Voltage-Charger/dp/B008NKNHSG). But I guess any DC/DC converter with enough power / cooling will do. However, I [encountered a problem](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/194429/45492), which seems related to 18.5V MBPs.

Comment: Hi @n1000 thanks for the DC/DC link. BTW I can't access the "encountered a problem" link. :(

Answer (score -2):

Use a DC to AC inverter.
You simply attach the alligator clips to the correct battery terminals, turn the device on  and plug your cord into the inverter. It's that simple.
Amazon sells a 400 watt inverter for $25, that's all you'll need.
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001RNOHBC/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RNOHBC)

Comment: The system should be as energy-efficient as possible. Doing DC-AC-DC involves quite some losses and is therefore unsuitable for my situation / question.

Comment: Inverters are fairly close to 100% efficient these days, which is why 500 W inverters only have tiny power supplies.