# Is it possible to "shut off" battery charging in OSX

Tags: macos, applescript, development, power-management

Is it possible to "shut off" battery charging in OSX with an application rather then physically. Could this be done with AppleScript (I doubt it) or will need to be obj-c cocoa application? Essentially my idea is an app that'll shut off the charger when requirements are met (like the computer is in sleep mode, or the battery hasn't been drained in a few days)

Comment: SMC will manage charger a whole lot better than any human ever could.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I you already tried looking on Google, but this a problem multiple persons have tried to do.

There doesn't seems to be a Public API (yet ?) also no "private" API has been found yet.

Also, as stated in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge), MacBooks have intelligent battery management. This means your laptop will stop charging once the battery is full.

---

Edit :

Results I found :

- [SO question : Is there a way to turn off battery charging programmatically in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168214/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-battery-charging-programmatically-in-osx)
- [Mac Rumors topic : Make battery stop charging at a certain level](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=862619)
- [Mac rumors topic : Program to disable charging](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1667538)
- [Ask Different question : How to disable battery charging?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87924/how-to-disable-battery-charging/132332#132332)

Comment: I know Macbooks have intelligent battery management but Id like to take it a step further. And yes i searched Google but couldnt come up with much. Could you link me to some of these places where other people have talked about doing this and the issues they have faced? I must not be searching the right phrases :)