# Audio warning to warn you that your laptop's battery is low

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery, notifications

I have two computers where I work back and forth, sometimes I'll launch a render on the MBP and go work on the iMac.

But sometimes, I unplug the MBP, go do something else, and rendering uses up all of the battery, which in turn makes the computer shut down mid-process if I'm not aware of the battery's condition.

[image]

I then have to plug it in, restart the computer, resume work if I haven't lost anything in the process.

I would love to know if there's a way to get an audio warning at some point while the battery is declining, like an alarm, this way I would be able to go plug it in even if I'm doing something else in another part of the house.

I looked in the System Preferences, but didn't find anything. I *don't* want the computer to go to sleep when the battery declines, but instead warn me, so I can plug it and avoid it dying.

[image]

I found [this](http://lifehacker.com/5769174/give-your-mac-a-more-attention-grabbing-low-battery-warning) but it seems a bit hard to setup.

I found [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167363/customize_your_macs_battery_warnings_with_low_battery_saver.html) article too, which doesn't explain very well what this app does.

In this [discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/456928?start=0&tstart=0), a user talks about an app that another user later on criticizes.

I'm not sure I want to try all three of these apps, and then have to go through uninstalling them if they don't do what I'm looking for.

So, is there a simple way to get this kind of warning?

*EDIT: following the numerous comments, I would add that the solution has to work in situations where I don't have a charger at hand, or where I'm out of the house, for example if I'm out of the house with no charger, working in another part of the office than the one my computer is in, in order to be warned to save my documents before the battery dies.*

Comment: A notification should appear when your battery level gets low. Was that removed in 10.11?

Comment: It might have been removed, but if you read my question entirely, you might seen that I can be far away from the computer when I need to plug it in and that I am looking for a real "alarm" (think alarm clock) not a visual message

Comment: Well my original idea was to connect the Mac to some speakers and then just turn up the volume when you leave so you can hear it from far away. Also, why do you unplug? Why not just run on AC power?

Comment: Won't the battery last longer if I let it go down from time to time? I've heard keeping a laptop on AC all the time is bad for the battery's lifespan (esp. older laptops). I like the speakers idea but it requires having speakers! And plugging them in. And it'll just go "ding" once, only louder... Not sure I'll hear it.

Comment: I'm currently employing [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132332/61861) solution to run on AC power without letting my battery charge. By staying constantly at around 50% (the optimum charge for long term storage) I can keep my battery healthy despite constantly working at a desk on AC power.

Comment: Interesting... looks like a great way to start a fire too ;) I appreciate your input, but let's try to stay on topic, as there are situations when I am outside of the house where it would be important that I am notified that I need to charge (working in wilderness, or working in an office when I don't have my cable, then moving to another part of the office, etc)

Comment: FWIW - the first solution you mentioned, the lifehacker Applescript, is a very decent solution.   The article even gives a YouTube video walking you through the instructions.    If you follow along carefully, it should take no more than 3-5 minutes tops to copy and paste everything per the instructions.    I'd really recommend giving it a shot.

Comment: @Charlie74 I gave up and tried, since no serious answer to do this was posted - alas, it was a big fail. After proceeding to the installation, nothing happened but the usual tiny & unnoticeable warning message on my screen... So, still unanswered to me!