# Disable MacBook Pro 16 m1 max charging with magsafe3

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery, charging

I want to get the new macbook with magsafe3, I am thinking of getting the 16 inch max 64gb version.

I currently have a 2015 retina and I disable charging using this method [How to disable battery charging?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87924/how-to-disable-battery-charging) which blocks the middle pin. I have been doing it for 7 years with no issue.

Has anyone been able to try this with the new m1 macs with magsafe3? If not could someone try and post on whether it works?

It should say power connected but not charging and the led light turns off after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a free cli tool, https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery, works like a charm, you need to type `battery charging on` into the terminal before you unplug it and you need to type `battery charging off` before you plug it in.

Comment: This answer seems a bit spammy.. you posted the [same answer](https://superuser.com/a/1734855/399707) on SuperUser

Comment: Yeah because I just found it and I wanted to add on to that answer as well.

Comment: OK, fair enough...