# My macbook battery is fully charged on menu bar but on Coconut Battery says charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

Here is my screenshot when my fully charged but still charging:

[image]

After a few minutes not charging again:

[image]

I'm just wondering, will my MacBook overcharge or over discharge or this is normal behavior?
Why design capacity is not consistent, sometimes 74%, 75%, 80%, etc.

Comment: And your battery ws really manufactured in the year 1400 ?

Comment: @SolarMike after I installed latest coconutBattery, it's shows 1438 Hijri Year or about 2017  gregorian year

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems normal to me.

Batteries are much more complex than most people think. There are many factors such as heat/temperature, actual charge, power draw, lifecycle/age,... that contribute into "inconsistent" measurements.

> Why design capacity is not consistent, sometimes 74%, 75%, 80%?

This is completely normal and every battery experiences this, especially as they get older. This again depends on many factors and the number will decrease over time/cycles.

> I'm just wondering, will my MacBook overcharge or over discharge or this is normal behavior?

When at 100% your battery will stop charging. It will start charging again, usually a couple percent below 100% if continually connected to power. macOS tries to smoothen the curve, i.e. it makes you think its constantly at 100%, which it isn't. This behaviour is normal.

There are many excellent articles that can explain the physical details much better than I can, but there isn't really anything you should/shouldn't do with your MacBook in terms of battery, [except trying to not (over)heat it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17303/what-are-the-best-practices-for-battery-longevity). So just use your MacBook, but don't put it in bright sunlight for example.